# google triggers stopped executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have been using a number of triggers based on form submission to a google sheet. Since yesterday the triggers have stopped working.

I have

1. unlinked and re-linked the form and sheet.
2. created a new response sheet.
3. recreated my scripts,
4. tried macros ( its a simple operation to sort the google sheet responses and send the top most response to another sheet )
5. the form submit trigger doesnt work. so to test I setup time based triggers. they seemed to work but stopped at 5 am this morning.

I can run the script manually and works fine but triggers do not run.
There was nothing in the logs. each trigger just stopped firing

Can anyone advise ?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you haven't exceeded your quota?

Comment: Can you check the logs on your AppsScript Project, and add it to the question ?

Comment: Do you see anything in the execution logs?

Comment: Hello - there was nothing in the logs . each trigger just stopped firing . Can you you tell me how i can check my quots ?  Many thanks

Comment: What runtime are you using? Have you tried to delete and recreate the triggers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to confirm the issue

## Problem

- installable trigger `onFormSubmit` from GoogleSheet stopped executing.
- installable trigger `onMinute`  from the same Spreadsheet still working and showing logs.

Logs are empty here:

`https://script.google.com/home/projects/PROJECT/executions`

## Solution?

My attempts to resolve the issue:

1. Delete and create trigger again
2. Change the source code
3. Create 2 same triggers.

Possible other tests:

1. Create trigger from another account
2. Create a trigger with no code to test if it could execute at all.

## Conclusion

In the end, one of my newly created triggers started the execution again.
I do not know what fixed the problem: changing the function text OR creating/deleting triggers OR some external fix on the Google side.

If some have more issues, please report the issue here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222